# Change of Measure for Jump Process with Drift and no Brownian motion

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, jump

If on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, $r>0$ is a constant and $Z_t =\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are i.i.d with $E[Y_i]=L$ denotes the size of the jump and can have distributions like normal, exponential, etc; $N_t$ is the Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. If $X_t$ is given by
$$dX_t = X_t(rdt -g(X(t))d(Z_t-\lambda Lt))$$

where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-0$ is Lipschitz continuous function.

My question is how do we get a risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$ and the Radon Nikodym derivative so that we have a form like
$$dX_t = X_t(\theta(t)d\tilde{Z}_t)$$
under the new measure where $\tilde{Z}$ is the compensated Poisson process under $\mathbb{Q}$?

In order to get a risk-neutral measure, we can further impose some restrictions on $g$.